# Added PowerMock to my gradle file, now when building, I get ZipException: duplicate entry: org/junit/ClassRule.class

Tags: android, gradle, powermock

Added PowerMock to my gradle file, now when building, I get ZipException: duplicate entry: org/junit/ClassRule.class

This is the relevant part of my `build.gradle`

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
androidTestCompile('junit:junit-dep:4.+') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest'
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
}
androidTestCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.3') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core' exclude module: 'objenesis'
}
```

How do I exclude `junit` from the powermock declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `exclude module: 'junit'` did it:

```
androidTestCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.3') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    exclude module: 'objenesis'
    exclude module: 'junit'
}
```